# Activities can't be added until the containing group has been created

Tags: android

Activities can't be added until the containing group has been created, error

Can any one help, below is the code im using.

```
try{
                                Intent previewMessage = new Intent(Home.this, a.class);
                                System.out.println("preview message "+previewMessage);

                                a insA = new a();

                                TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)insA;
                                System.out.println("parentActivity message "+parentActivity);

                                parentActivity.startChildActivity("home", previewMessage);

                                }catch(Exception ex){
                                    System.out.println("Caought exception :- "+ex.getMessage());
                                }
```